# how to print sub tasks with its task list in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have project management tool in laravel 5.2 and this application have project create and one project have tasks and each task have sub tasks. currently I am displaying projects and its tasks as well. Now I need display sub tasks witch related to each project and task. project->task->subtasks
this is my task displacing method

tasks/index.blade.php

```
  @foreach ($project->tasks as $task)
{{ $task->task_name }}
@endforeach
```

this is displaing in the projects/show.blade.php

```
<h5><b>Tasks List</b></h5>
@if($project)
  @include('tasks.index')
@endif
```

now I need display task's sub tasks in the project/show.blade.php

this is my subtask store method

```
public function store(Request $request,$projectId,$taskId)
    {
        $subtask = new Subtask;
        $subtask->subtask_name = $request->input('task_name');
        $subtask->task_id = $taskId;
        $subtask->project_id = $projectId;
        $subtask->save();

      return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Task created successfully');
}
```

this is subtask table

```
id  subtask_name  task_id  project_id
 1      abc          1         1
 2      hfy          2         1
 3      jhu          2         2
 5      lop          1         3
```

how can I print my sub tasks related each task?

Comment: I need some guideline...

Comment: you need some relationships see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I have relationship between project , task and sub task table

Comment: then you do something like `{{ $task->subtask}}` to get the subtasks

Comment: in witch file..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown in your question where you'd like to output the `subtask`s.

However, you basically want to eager load your relations in your controller, prior to using the data in your view to avoid executing a separate query for every task and subtasks.

```
// ProjectController
// You may have other conditions, etc on your query. But you want to use `with('tasks.subtasks')`
$project = Project::with('tasks.subtasks')->find(1);

// project/show.blade.php
@foreach ($project->tasks as $task)
    {{ $task->task_name }}
    @foreach ($task->subtasks as $subtask)
        {{ $subtask->subtask_name }}            
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: I need print My sub tasks in projects/show.blade.php file after eash its parent tasks. see my task showing file in my question

Comment: can you briefly describe what is the meaning of this code **$projects = Project::with('tasks.subtasks')->get();**

Comment: The `with()` function will eager load model relations (it works with nested relations too). Laravel will do this using a `WHERE id IN (...)` query for all the models found. It therefore loads data using far few queries than it'd use lazy loading the same data.

Comment: put it in ProjectController but occurred this error **syntax error, unexpected '$projects' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)**

Comment: You put it in one of your controller actions? I was assuming if you'd built your application this far, you'd know where to put that line of code.